# Excessive div when browser-sync refreshing

Tags: html, css, sass, gulp

when I'm refreshing sass file, a new div is added to the page, when I'm refreshing html file this extra div disappears

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        opacity: 0;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    html {
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div>
            <p>H</p>
        </div>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.min.css">
        <script src="js/scripts.min.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

[Pastebin CSS](https://pastebin.com/5zLeCuKX)
[Img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnSZD.png)

[image]

Comment: It works fine. Your CSS is alright. Check here https://jsfiddle.net/pn2tmn5s/ . It may be because of Javascript.

Comment: I tried to delete js

Comment: Set an ID for your div and set the style for the same, instead of div element in your CSS.

Comment: It's not visible now but this div still exist